# DepthwiseConv2D layer with same kernel for all channels

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tf.keras

I found DepthwiseConv2D class [here](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/depthwise_convolution2d/).
It uses a unique kernel for each channel of the input image.
But is it possible to use the same kernel for all channels?(i.e. Parameter sharing within the layer)

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation I think the same kernel is used on all channels so the kernel weights are shared accross the different channels. An easy way to confirm this is to create a model using a `DepthwiseConv2D` with `depth_multiplier=1` and to print how many parameters can be trained. For a `3x3` kernel you should get 10 parameters (9 kernel ones + bias).